# Discord.js el mensaje de bienvenida se repite por siempre

Tags: nodejs

Ok, este es el problema, tengo mi codigo que es

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('717814457140641812').send(`**¡Hola <@` + member.user.id + `>!** Bienvenido a **` + serverName + `**, recuerda leer las <#719847936896401472>, <#718081678765195366> y <#717823857179885721>, ¡Disfruta!.`)
});
```

Pero al momento de usarlo, se repite infinitamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error estaría en `client.on`, tendrias qué remplazarlo por `bot.on` y en `member.guild.channels.cache.get` tienes qué remplazarlo por `member.guild.channels.get`, te dejo el código correcto abajo. Si ves qué sigue enviando mensajes sin parar, no dudes en contactar conmigo desde Discord: Dani ♡#0348

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('717814457140641812').send(`**¡Hola <@` + member.user.id + `>!** Bienvenido a **` + serverName + `**, recuerda leer las <#719847936896401472>, <#718081678765195366> y <#717823857179885721>, ¡Disfruta!.`); 
});
```

Saludos.